# Subtract one hour from datetime rather than one day

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have a `datetime` column in Oracle (*MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM*) but when I do this:

```
SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-1 FROM tbl1
```

...it goes back a day. How do I remove one hour from the column rather than one day?

I've also noticed that the `datetime` records for 12AM look like *MM/DD/YYYY* and not *MM/DD/YYYY 00:00:00*; I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: How are you viewing the 12AM values? Is it through SQLPlus or a front-end language (C#, PHP, etc., etc.)?

Comment: using Toad, is the front end the issue? I'm new the the Oracle env

Comment: It could be a TOAD thing, but I'm not familiar with TOAD. If all the other dates in the column show the time component and the "midnight" dates don't, I think it's safe to assume that the "midnight" is really there and TOAD is just "helpfully" hiding it. There may be a setting where you can turn this feature on or off, but that's just a guess. I do know that the .NET languages and PHP will recognize the time portion - even if it's zero - and probably just about every other language will too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Randy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084524/1083652) is good, but you can also use intervals:

```
SELECT MAX(D_DTM)- interval '1' hour FROM tbl1
```

Comment: better answer IMO, more clear for future coders to know whats going on

Answer (score 7):

Or use the `INTERVAL` function. It has the same result but I think it reads more clearly - that's of course just an opinion :)

```
SELECT MAX(D_DTM) - INTERVAL '1' HOUR FROM tbl1
```

The nice thing about the `INTERVAL` function is that you can make the interval be years, months, days, hours, minutes or seconds when dealing with a `DATE` value, though the month interval can be tricky when dealing with end-of-month dates.

And yes, the quote around the `1` in the example is required.

You can also use the Oracle-specific `NumToDSInterval` function, which is less standard but more flexible because it accepts variables instead of constants:

```
SELECT MAX(D_DTM) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'HOUR') FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 6):

yes - dates go by integer days.

if you want hours you need to do some math - like `-(1/24)`

Answer (score 5):

```
select sysdate - numtodsinterval(1,'hour') from dual
```

Answer (score 4):

Its simple.

sysdate - 5/(24*60*60) --> Subtracts 5 seconds from systime

sysdate - 5/(24*60)    --> Subtracts 5 minutes from systime

sysdate - 5/(24)       --> Subtracts 5 hours from systime

Hence

select (sysdate - (1/24)) from dual

Comment: Can you expand a little more on your answer, such as why you are using division to subtract?

Comment: @CodyGuldner The division is computing the value as a fraction of days. (1 hour is 1/24 of a day, so 5/24 days is 5 hours.) The subtraction then subtracts day. Personally, though, I'd be worried about floating point errors.

Comment: @jpmc26 The idea is that information like that should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another method of using intervals is

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL( number, expression )
```

examples

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL(150, 'DAY')
NUMTODSINTERVAL(1500, 'HOUR')
NUMTODSINTERVAL(15000, 'MINUTE')
NUMTODSINTERVAL(150000, 'SECOND')
```

I bring this up because it is useful for situations where using INTERVAL wont work.